# netsh equivalent command in OSX

Tags: network, bash

How would I construct the bash equivalent of this command?

```
netsh -c interface ipv4 add neighbors "Wi-Fi" "10.0.1.1" "b8:8d:12:57:2d:50" store=persistent
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the equivalent:

```
sudo arp -S 10.0.1.1 b8:8d:12:57:2d:50 ifscope en0
```